# MongoDB Failing to Start - ***

Tags: mongodb

I have configured mongodb with yu on linux.

enabled systemctl enable mongod.service as well, when ever exit do ctrl+c,

systemctl status mongod.service status is failed

mongod --port 27017 says connecting.. but status is still failed.

netstat show port 27017 is listening

any suggestions?

db version 3.2.4, in rc.d/init.d not able to find mondo script, for chkconfig mongod on

Comment: Can you please clarify/rephrase as to what the problem is? Its not quite clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: Would you be able to share with us mongodb logs. It should say why it fails. I think the default is /var/log/mongo* or if you did systemd, it might be in syslog

Comment: when started service using sudo service mongod start, then it is directed to /bin/systemctl, systemctl start mongod.service

Comment: 2017-10-21T13:24:59.543-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { config: "/etc/mongod.conf", net: { bindIp: "127.0.0.1", port: 27017 }, processManagement: { fork: true, pidFilePath: "/var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid" }, storage: { dbPath: "/var/lib/mongo", journal: { enabled: true } }, systemLog: { destination: "file", logAppend: true, path: "/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log" } }

Comment: 2017-10-21T13:24:59.567-0400 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=7431M,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),checkpoint=(wait=60,log_size=2GB),statistics_log=(wait=0),
2017-10-21T13:24:59.599-0400 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (2) [1508606699:599454][21079:0x7f0950536e40], file:WiredTiger.wt, connection: /var/lib/mongo/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: No such file or directory

Comment: 2017-10-21T13:24:59.601-0400 I -        [initandlisten] Assertion: 28595:2: No such file or directory src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_kv_engine.cpp 269

Comment: 2017-10-21T13:24:59.611-0400 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 28595 2: No such file or directory, terminating
2017-10-21T13:24:59.611-0400 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2017-10-21T13:24:59.611-0400 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] removing socket file: /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
2017-10-21T13:24:59.611-0400 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
2017-10-21T13:24:59.611-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
2017-10-21T13:24:59.611-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:100

Comment: mongod --port 27017
2017-10-21T22:48:58.386-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=23091 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=bmdctlvxwki01
2017-10-21T22:48:58.386-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.4.9
2017-10-21T22:48:58.386-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 876ebee8c7d0e2d992f36a848ff4dc50ee6603e
2017-10-21T22:48:58.386-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
2017-10-21T22:48:58.386-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc

Comment: 2017-10-21T22:48:58.386-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2017-10-21T22:48:58.386-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2017-10-21T22:48:58.386-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] distmod: rhel70
2017-10-21T22:48:58.386-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2017-10-21T22:48:58.386-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2017-10-21T22:48:58.386-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { net: { port:27017 } }

Comment: 2017-10-21T22:48:58.412-0400 I -        [initandlisten] Detected data files in /data/db created by the 'wiredTiger' storageengine, so setting the active storage engine to 'wiredTiger'

Comment: 2017-10-21T22:48:58.412-0400 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config:                                           create,cache_size=7431M,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4)                       ,config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal                               ,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),checkpoint=(wait=60,log_size=2GB),statistics_log=(wait=0),

Comment: 2017-10-21T22:48:58.692-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2017-10-21T22:48:58.692-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database.
2017-10-21T22:48:58.692-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
2017-10-21T22:48:58.692-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: You are running this process as the root user, which is not recommended.

Comment: 2017-10-21T22:48:58.692-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2017-10-21T22:48:58.693-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2017-10-21T22:48:58.693-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled is 'always'.
2017-10-21T22:48:58.693-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **We suggest setting it to 'never'
2017-10-21T22:48:58.693-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2017-10-21T22:48:58.693-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag is 'always'.

Comment: 2017-10-21T22:48:58.693-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** We suggest setting it to 'never'
2017-10-21T22:48:58.693-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2017-10-21T22:48:58.698-0400 I FTDC     [initandlisten] Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture with directory '/data/db/diagnostic.data'

Comment: 2017-10-21T22:48:58.699-0400 I NETWORK  [thread1] waiting for connections on port 27017

Comment: @Dhruv I think I know what your issue is. But could you please add the log file and the systemctl output into your OP and remove the comments with the output in? It’s really hard to read the output when there in the comments :-)